# python regrex not able to fetch data

Tags: python, regex-group

Problem : My objective is to fetch all the phone numbers from file. 
I am able to fetch all the phones except the one for user named as "*suneja, amit*" present in the second to last line in the data file.
I was able to fetch it till step3 of code where I have used 3 groups. But it is not coming up when I tried to use 4th group.

Here is Data File:

```
Love, Kenneth   kenneth@teamtreehouse.com   +1 (555) 555-5555   Teacher, Treehouse  @kennethlove
McFarland, Dave dave@teamtreehouse.com  (555) 555-5554  Teacher, Treehouse
Arthur, King    king_arthur@camelot.co.uk   King, Camelot
Österberg, Sven-Erik    governor@norrbotten.co.se       Governor, Norrbotten    @sverik
, Tim   tim@killerrabbit.com        Enchanter, Killer Rabbit Cave
Carson, Ryan    ryan@teamtreehouse.com  (555) 555-5543  CEO, Treehouse  @ryancarson
Doctor, The doctor+companion@tardis.co.uk       Time Lord, Gallifrey
Exampleson, Example me@example.com  +1-555-555-5552 Example, Example Co.    @example
Obama, Barack   president.44@us.gov 555 555-5551    President, United States of America @potus44
Chalkley, Andrew    andrew@teamtreehouse.com    (555) 555-5553  Teacher, Treehouse  @chalkers
Vader, Darth    darth-vader@empire.gov  (555).555.4444  Sith Lord, Galactic Empire  @darthvader
suneja, amit    amit.suneja007@gmail.com 444-444444   B102, City Center @programmer
Fernndez de la Vega Sanz, María Teresa  mtfvs@spain.gov     First Deputy Prime Minister, Spanish Govt.
```

Here is my code:

```
import re
data_file = 'names.txt'

with open(data_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    data_dump = myfile.read()

print("___________________________________")
print(re.findall(r"(\+\d[\-\s])", data_dump))
print("___________________________________")
print(re.findall(r"(\+\d[\s\-])?(\(?\d{3}\)?)", data_dump))
print("___________________________________")
print(re.findall(r"(\+\d[\s\-])?(\(?\d{3}\)?)([\s\-.]\d{3})", data_dump))
print("___________________________________")
print(re.findall(r"(\+\d[\s\-])?(\(?\d{3}\)?)([\s\-.]\d{3})([\s.-]\d{4,6})", data_dump))
print(len(re.findall(r"(\+\d[\s\-])?(\(?\d{3}\)?)([\s\-.]\d{3})([\s.-]\d{4,6})", data_dump)))
```

Here is my Output of Code:

```
___________________________________
['+1 ', '+1-']
___________________________________
[('+1 ', '(555)'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '(555)'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '(555)'), ('', '555'), ('', '554'), ('+1-', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '(555)'), ('', '555'), ('', '555'), ('', '(555)'), ('', '555'), ('', '444'), ('', '007'), ('', '444'), ('', '444'), ('', '444'), ('', '102')]
___________________________________
[('+1 ', '(555)', ' 555'), ('', '(555)', ' 555'), ('', '(555)', ' 555'), ('+1-', '555', '-555'), ('', '555', ' 555'), ('', '(555)', ' 555'), ('', '(555)', '.555'), ('', '444', '-444')]
___________________________________
[('+1 ', '(555)', ' 555', '-5555'), ('', '(555)', ' 555', '-5554'), ('', '(555)', ' 555', '-5543'), ('+1-', '555', '-555', '-5552'), ('', '555', ' 555', '-5551'), ('', '(555)', ' 555', '-5553'), ('', '(555)', '.555', '.4444')]
7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a little change on your last regex to make it work:

```
(\+\d[\s\-])?(\(?\d{3}\)?)([\s\-.]\d{3})([\s.-]?\d{3,6})
```

The change was only in the last capture group putting the question mark in: `([\s.-]?\d{3,6})`

The question mark in that group makes the [\s.-] optional. Since your last phone number doesn't have any of those characters, they have to be optional

Comment: Thanks it worked for me . Can you explain the the change you made in my code ?

Comment: Updated the answer with the explanation